# How hashmap identifies when it needs rehashing

Tags: java, hashmap

How Hashmap identifies that this bucket is full and it needs rehashing as it stores the value in linked list if two hashcodes are same, then as per my understanding this linkedlist does not have any fixed size and it can store as many elements it can so this bucket will never be full then how it will identify that it needs rehashing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a `ConcurrentHashMap` actually a red-black tree (for large number of elements) or a linked list (for small number of elements) is used when there is a collision (i.e. two different keys have the same hash code). But you are right when you say, the linked list (or red-black tree) can grow infinitely (assuming you have infinite memory and heap size).

The basic idea of a `HashMap` or `ConcurrentHashMap` is, you want to retrieve a value based on its key in **O(1)** time complexity. But in reality, collisions do happen and when that happens we put the nodes in a tree linked to the bucket (or array cell). So, Java could create a `HashMap` where the array size would remain fixed and rehashing would never happen, but if they did that all your key values need to be accommodated within the fixed-size array (along with their linked trees).

Let's say you have that kind of `HashMap` where your array size is fixed to 16 and you push 1000 key-value pairs in it. In that case, you can have at most 16 distinct hash codes. This in turn means that you would have collisions in all (1000-16) `put`s and those new nodes will end up in the tree and they can no longer be fetched in O(1) time complexity. In tree you'd need O(log n) time to search for keys.

To make sure that this doesn't happen, the `HashMap` uses a load factor calculation to determine how much of the array is filled with key-value pairs. If it is 75% (default settings) full, any new `put` would create a new larger array, copy the existing content into it and thus have more buckets or hash code space. This ensures that in most of the cases collisions won't happen and the tree won't be required and you would fetch most keys in O(1) time.

Answer (score 0):

> Hashmap maintain complexity of O(1) while inserting data in and
>   getting data from hashmap, but for 13th key-value pair, put request
>   will no longer be O(1), because as soon as map will realize that 13th
>   element came in, that is 75% of map is filled.
>
> **It will first double the bucket(array) capacity and then it will go
>   for Rehash.** Rehashing requires re-computing hashcode of already placed
>   12 key-value pairs again and putting them at new index which requires
>   time.

[Kindly refer this link, this will be helpful for you.](http://javabypatel.blogspot.com/2015/10/what-is-load-factor-and-rehashing-in-hashmap.html)